# Vectorizing iterative array slicing in Numpy/Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to vectorize a numpy loop-process in which I iteratively slice an array with each loop:

```
for y in range(0, 10):
    maxpr[y] = npds[y*365:(y+1)*365].max(axis=0)
```

npds is a (3650, 192, 288) numpy array while maxpr is a (10,192,288) numpy array.

I am effectively trying to get rid of this `for` loop that iterates `y` through vectorization.

I have already tried something like:

```
years1 = np.arange(0,3650,365)
years2 = years1 + 365

maxpr = npds[years1:years2].argmax(axis=0)
```

but this returns an error of "*only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index*".

Please let me know if you have any suggestions; thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break the first dimension into 2, i.e. reshape the array to `(10, 365, 192, 288)` and then `max` along 2nd axis:

```
npds.reshape((10, 365, 192, 288)).max(axis=1)
```

---

*Example*:

```
npds = np.arange(24).reshape((6,2,2))
maxpr = np.empty((3,2,2))

for y in range(0, 3):
    maxpr[y] = npds[y*2:(y+1)*2].max(axis=0)

(npds.reshape((3,2,2,2)).max(axis=1) == maxpr).all()
# True
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly, and is an elegant/simple solution.